# Merging multiple uv maps with textures into one

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, uv, texture-baking

I have 11 mesh items with 11 individual UV maps that have already been connected to 11 separate image textures.

[image: Outliner view of meshes with individual texture materials]

When I combine the meshes into one mesh, I have many overlapping faces in the resulting UV map, and re-sizing the islands distorts the textures.

[image: Overlapping faces in UV map]

Is there a way to avoid manually re-arranging the textures to a new, single UV, such as with texture baking?

Note that this is in the Cycles render engine.

Comment: You can try to rename UV maps before joining objects. As they are named differently, Blender won't join them. *But* there's a limitation to UV maps quantity. Probably it's possible to combine e.g. 7 at once, bake texture, delete these 7 and so on. Not sure if it's convenient though.

Comment: Unfortunately I think my skill in Blender is too little to wrap my head around texture baking, so I'm just going to redo the single texture. Thank you very much for trying, and maybe I can attempt this when I know a bit more what I'm doing :)

Comment: Have a look at the [texture atlas addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas)